# Atmosphere Multiple streaming XmlHttpRequests (XHR)/Channels block?

Tags: javascript, comet, xmlhttprequest, atmosphere

I am building an web app which uses Comet. The backend side is build with Atmosphere and Jersey. However I ran into trouble when i wanted to subscribe to multiple channels. The jQuery plugin atmosphere supplies only has support for 1 channel. I started to write my own implementation as for comet that is for the moment.

*THE PROBLEM*

**If i update channel 1 with msg "Hello" i don't get notified. However when i update channel 2 with msg "World" afterwards. I get both "Hello" and "World" at the same time..**

```
var connection1 = new AtmosphereConnectionComet("http://localhost/b/product/status/1");
var connection2 = new AtmosphereConnectionComet("http://localhost/b/product/status/2");

var handleMessage = function(msg)
{
   alert(msg);
};

connection1.NewMessage.add(handleMessage);
connection2.NewMessage.add(handleMessage);

connection1.connect();
connection2.connect();
```

The AtmosphereConnectionComet implementation:

**UPDATED**

- Added the fixes of Ivo (scoping and instatantion issue)
- Fixed the <--EOD--> indexOf to capture the atmosphere message
- Added comments to the onIncoming XHR method

```
function AtmosphereConnectionComet(url)
{
    //signals for dispatching
    this.Connected = new signals.Signal();
    this.Disconnected = new signals.Signal();
    this.NewMessage = new signals.Signal();

    //private vars
    var xhr = null;
    var self = this;
    var gotWelcomeMessage = false;
    var readPosition;
    var url = url;

    //private methods
    var onIncomingXhr = function()
    {
        //check if we got some new data
        if (xhr.readyState == 3)
        {
            //if the status is oke
            if (xhr.status==200)  // Received a message
            {
                //get the message
                //this is like streaming.. each time we get readyState 3 and status 200 there will be text appended to xhr.responseText
                var message = xhr.responseText;

                console.log(message);

                //check if we dont have the welcome message yet and if its maybe there... (it doesn't come in one pull)
                if(!gotWelcomeMessage && message.indexOf("<--EOD-->") > -1)
                {
                    //we has it
                    gotWelcomeMessage = true;
                    //dispatch a signal
                    self.Connected.dispatch(sprintf("Connected to %s", url));
                }
                //welcome message set, from now on only messages (yes this will fail for larger date i presume)
                else
                {
                    //dispatch the new message by substr from the last readPosition
                    self.NewMessage.dispatch(message.substr(readPosition));
                }

                //update the readPosition to the size of this message
                readPosition = xhr.responseText.length;
            }
        }
        //ooh the connection got resumed, seems we got disconnected
        else if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //disconnect
            self.disconnect();
        }
    }

    var getXhr = function()
    {
        if ( window.location.protocol !== "file:" ) {
            try {
                return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch(xhrError) {}
        }

        try {
            return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(activeError) {}
    }

    this.connect = function()
    {
        xhr = getXhr();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = onIncomingXhr;
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }

    this.disconnect = function()
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = null;
        xhr.abort();
    }

    this.send = function(message)
    {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 9-1 23:00 GMT+1**

It seems atmosphere doesn't output the stuff..

*ProductEventObserver*

This is a ProductEventObserver which observes SEAM events. This component is autocreated and is in the APPLICATION context of SEAM. It catches the events and uses the broadcastToProduct to get the right broadcaster (via the broadcasterfactory) and broadcast the json message (i used gson as json serializer/marshaller) to the supspended connections.

```
package nl.ambrero.botenveiling.managers.product;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import nl.ambrero.botenveiling.entity.product.Product;
import nl.ambrero.botenveiling.entity.product.ProductBid;
import nl.ambrero.botenveiling.entity.product.ProductBidRetraction;
import nl.ambrero.botenveiling.entity.product.ProductRetraction;
import nl.ambrero.botenveiling.managers.EventTypes;
import nl.ambrero.botenveiling.rest.vo.*;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.Broadcaster;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterFactory;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.*;
import org.jboss.seam.log.Log;

@Name("productEventObserver")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@AutoCreate
public class ProductEventObserver
{
    @Logger
    Log logger;

    Gson gson;

    @Create
    public void init()
    {
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    private void broadCastToProduct(int id, ApplicationEvent message)
    {
        Broadcaster broadcaster = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(DefaultBroadcaster.class, String.format("%s", id));

        logger.info(String.format("There are %s broadcasters active", BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookupAll().size()));

        if(broadcaster == null)
        {
            logger.info("No broadcaster found..");

            return;
        }

        logger.info(String.format("Broadcasting message of type '%s' to '%s' with scope '%s'", message.getEventType(), broadcaster.getID(), broadcaster.getScope().toString()));

        broadcaster.broadcast(gson.toJson(message));
    }

    @Observer(value = { EventTypes.PRODUCT_AUCTION_EXPIRED, EventTypes.PRODUCT_AUCTION_SOLD })
    public void handleProductAcutionEnded(Product product)
    {
        this.broadCastToProduct(
            product.getId(),
            new ProductEvent(ApplicationEventType.PRODUCT_AUCTION_ENDED, product)
        );
    }

    @Observer(value = EventTypes.PRODUCT_RETRACTED)
    public void handleProductRetracted(ProductRetraction productRetraction)
    {
        this.broadCastToProduct(
            productRetraction.getProduct().getId(),
            new ProductRetractionEvent(ApplicationEventType.PRODUCT_RETRACTED, productRetraction)
        );
    }

    @Observer(value = EventTypes.PRODUCT_AUCTION_STARTED)
    public void handleProductAuctionStarted(Product product)
    {
        this.broadCastToProduct(
            product.getId(),
            new ProductEvent(ApplicationEventType.PRODUCT_AUCTION_STARTED, product)
        );
    }

    @Observer(value = EventTypes.PRODUCT_BID_ADDED)
    public void handleProductNewBid(ProductBid bid)
    {
        this.broadCastToProduct(
            bid.getProduct().getId(),
            new ProductBidEvent(ApplicationEventType.PRODUCT_BID_ADDED, bid)
        );
    }

    @Observer(value = EventTypes.PRODUCT_BID_RETRACTED)
    public void handleProductRetractedBid(ProductBidRetraction bidRetraction)
    {
        this.broadCastToProduct(
            bidRetraction.getProductBid().getProduct().getId(),
            new ProductBidRetractionEvent(ApplicationEventType.PRODUCT_BID_RETRACTED, bidRetraction)
        );
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>nl.ambrero.botenveiling.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useWebSocket</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/b/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

atmosphere.xml

```
<atmosphere-handlers>
    <atmosphere-handler context-root="/b" class-name="org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor">
        <property name="servletClass" value="com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer"/>
    </atmosphere-handler>
</atmosphere-handlers>
```

Broadcaster:

```
@Path("/product/status/{product}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProductEventBroadcaster
{
    @PathParam("product")
    private Broadcaster product;

    @GET
    public SuspendResponse subscribe()
    {
        return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder()
                .broadcaster(product)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 10-1 4:18 GMT+1**

- The following console output shows
  that the broadcasters are found and
  are active.
- I updated the broadcastToProduct to the full class code
- Updated the start paragraph with the problem
- Added web.xml and atmosphere.xml

Console output:

```
16:15:16,623 INFO  [STDOUT] 16:15:16,623 INFO  [ProductEventObserver] There are 3 broadcasters active
16:15:16,624 INFO  [STDOUT] 16:15:16,624 INFO  [ProductEventObserver] Broadcasting message of type 'productBidAdded' to '2' with scope 'APPLICATION'
16:15:47,580 INFO  [STDOUT] 16:15:47,580 INFO  [ProductEventObserver] There are 3 broadcasters active
16:15:47,581 INFO  [STDOUT] 16:15:47,581 INFO  [ProductEventObserver] Broadcasting message of type 'productBidAdded' to '1' with scope 'APPLICATION'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of product:

```
@PathParam("product")
private Broadcaster product;
```

Does it match the id of the broadCastToProduct(int id, ApplicationEvent message)?

Send me a test case I can look at (post it users@atmosphere.java.net).

Comment: Thanks for repling! The broadcaster is found, see the my start post ( i updated it with the console output (this shows the broadcaster is found), added the code of the class and clarified the problem)

Comment: First, you don't need atmosphere.xml in your case, and you don't need to specify com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages. Atmosphere will do it for you. I clearly don't see by just reading why it doesn;t wrk. Can you send me the .war file at jfarcand [at] apache dot org?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the code you posted shouldn't work at all since `AtmosphereConnectionComet` does not create new objects.

```
function AtmosphereConnectionComet(url)
{
    this.Connected = new signals.Signal();
    this.Disconnected = new signals.Signal();
    this.NewMessage = new signals.Signal();
```

This is supposed to be a constructor, but you're not calling it as such:

```
var connection1 = AtmosphereConnectionComet(...);
```

You have to use the `new` keyword, so it will work like a constructor, otherwise `this` inside `AtmosphereConnectionComet` will not refer to a **new** object, but it will refer to the **window** object(!).

```
 var connection1 = new AtmosphereConnectionComet(...);
```

Now you will really have to distinct connections, before the second call did just overwrite the old stuff.

Have a look at how [Constructors](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#constructors) and [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#this) works in JavaScript.

**More problems**

```
        readPosition = this.responseText.length;
    }
} 
else if (this.readyState == 4)
```

Those `this` should rather be `xhr`, while they will work, due to the fact that the function gets called in the context of the request, for clarity you should stick to either `this` or `xhr`.

**Update**

Another Bug.

```
  else
    {
        self.NewMessage.dispatch(message.substr(readPosition));
    }

    // this should be before the above if statement
    readPosition = xhr.responseText.length;
```

Comment: You are right. I wrote the example code a bit quick, so i forgot about the "new". Fixed the this scoping problem (sharp +1). However it seems i doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: @mark Still wrapping my head around it, there's another bug, updates my answer. Make sure to update the complete code in your question afterwards so I can check for further issues.

Comment: The dispatching of new messages works actually. The readPosition is updated to the new length (because the response hangs) after the substr from the previous message is processed.

Comment: Added comments and stuff. As the comments say.. the responseText is streaming. So eachtime i get xhr.readyState 3 and xhr.status 200 there is new data appended to xhr.responseText. That's why i used the readPosition and update it after we substr to the end of the current response.

Comment: Digging through the Atmosphere docs, seems that you have to explicitly set `broadcaster.setScope(org.atmosphere.cpr.Broadcaster.SCOPE)` otherwise it will try to respond to all suspended responses, this is right now my best bet of what might be wrong :/

Comment: Good point, digged some in the sources of DefaultBroadcaster. Seems the Scope is by default set to APPLICATION which means as the docs say: "# APPLICATION: broadcast events to all AtmosphereResourceEvent created for the current web application." I tried changing it to VM, but as i thought it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I send my project to Jfarcand. He found out that Atmosphere 0.6.3 which I was using contained a bug with the ThreadPool. This should not be in 0.6.2. In 0.7-SNAPSHOT it was fixed aswell, bu I think he is working 0.6.4 where the bug is fixed aswell.